# How to get duration to show in Windows Explorer column?

Tags: windows-7

How to get duration to show in Windows Explorer column?

Here it is always empty: [image: screenshot]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The information you are wanting is actually in the `Length` column. That is enabled by default in Explorer.

Also, if you set the folders type template to `Music` it'll set it all up for you. It is in the `Customize` tab in the properties dialog for the folder (the first dropdown).

Comment: Thanks. I wonder what MS thinks Duration means, if not Length of a time period :)

Comment: I can't say for certain but I believe that there are two reasons. First, MS had a lot of issues with the duration column in XP. The problem is that duration is actually part of the meta data on these files. This means that you are able to enter whatever value you want for duration. The other issue is more general. Many formats are getting rid of the duration field because it is difficult to translate. Many languages don't have a separate word which means, 'length of time'. They just use 'length' so this led to a lot of confusion for those users.

Comment: "Many languages don't have a separate word which means, 'length of time'." You'd think MS could use 'Length of time', no? :) "They just use 'length' so this led to a lot of confusion for those users." As, so MS chose to spread the confusion to English too :) Thanks for the explanation.